# Sorting suggested words by usage from Lucene Dictionary

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, autosuggest

I'm beginner in Java/Lucene. I'm trying to sort first 20 suggested words by most used words in Lucene dictionary.

This code snippet returns me first 20 words beginning by character "a" from field "tokens":

```
AnalyzingSuggester suggester = new AnalyzingSuggester(dir, "sugest", new StandardAnalyzer(CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET));
suggester.build(new LuceneDictionary(indexReader, "tokens"));
List<LookupResult> lookupResults = suggester.lookup("a", false, 20);
```

but it is sorted in alphabetical order. I want to sort this by most used words (or "top ranking terms" as it is named in Luke). I found something about `Sort` and `SortField`, but I don't know how to use it in this suggesting scenario. Is there any easy solution for this task or do I need to write own functionality, where I need to get frequency of particular words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `HighFrequencyDictionary`, instead, like this:

```
AnalyzingSuggester suggester = new AnalyzingSuggester(dir, "sugest", new StandardAnalyzer(CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET));
suggester.build(new HighFrequencyDictionary(indexReader, "tokens", 0));
List<LookupResult> lookupResults = suggester.lookup("a", false, 20);
```